# How to insert line breaks on existing text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have an existing text file that is one long string. I would like to create a .bat script to insert a carriage return and line-feed after it finds `~`.

For example, the original text file is:

```
This is a long string~which should be many lines~and yet it is not
```

The wanted output is:

```
This is a long string~
which should be many lines~
and yet it is not
```

Comment: See [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Comment: I apologize since the formating didn't show up the way I wanted to. I wanted to return a new line after the tilde. Can use the post you reference and replace "~" with "~\r"? 
Is the return carriage "\r"?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure how to do tilde replacement within a batch file because the tilde is a special character within the SET command for substrings.

But this should get you headed in the right direction.

```
@echo off
set "longline=This is a long string~which should be many lines~and yet it is not"

set count=1
:loop
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=~" %%G IN ("%longline%") DO (
    SET "line%count%=%%G"
    set "longline=%%H"
    IF DEFINED longline (set /a count+=1 &goto loop)
)

FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%count%) DO call echo %%line%%I%%

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

First let me explain the three different types of line break/newline/line ending/line termination types.

There is [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) with the escape sequence `\r` with hexadecimal code value `0D` abbreviated with **CR** and [line-feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) with the escape sequence `\n` with hexadecimal code value `0A` abbreviated with **LF**.

- Text files on **MS-DOS/Windows** use **CR**+**LF** as newline.
- Text files on **Unix/Linux/MAC** (since OS X) use just **LF** as newline.
- Text files on **MAC** before OS X use just **CR** as newline.

So I suppose in real the task is to insert after [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) not just a carriage return, but a carriage return + line-feed.

The answers on [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/) offer many solutions for replacing strings in text files using Windows command line.

The first suggested solution is with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham**.

```
jrepl.bat "~" "~\r\n" /X /F "FileToModify.txt" /O -
```

This solution works for a text file containing the posted line and produce the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could also utilise PowerShell from your batch file too:

```bat
@If "%~1"=="" (Exit/B) Else If Not Exist "%~1" Exit/B
@Powershell -C "(GC '%~1') -Replace '~',\"`r`n\"|SC '%~1'"
```

The above accepts your input file as its argument, *which means it could be as simple as a drag and drop job*. The output file will be ASCII encoded by default.